# Find a solution of $x^3 - x-1=0$ in $[1,2]$

Tags: general-topology, banach-spaces

> Using Banach contraction theorem to find a solution of $x^3 - x-1=0$ in [$1,2$], by approximation.

Can anyone give an example of Banach contraction, so I can complete my lecture note to find a solution of $x^3 - x-1=0$ in $[1,2]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also known as the [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).  You want to find a function $f$ so that $f(x)=x$ at the root you are seeking and $|f'(x)| \lt q \lt 1$ over the interval $[1,2]$.  Then if you start at any $x_0 \in [1,2]$ and iterate $x_{i+1}=f(x_i)$ you will converge to the root you seek.  The derivative condition insures that you get closer and closer with each iteration.  A choice which fails is $f(x)=x^3-1$ because the derivative is too large.  You need to find another $f(x)$ that doesn't change so much with $x$.  You should present your $f(x)$, then show the result at each iteration until you have converged to acceptable accuracy.

Comment: do you have an example? thank you

Comment: can you help me to write down the solution of my question ? I can not find the right answer

Comment: The problem with powers is that they change rapidly.  The flip side is that roots change slowly, so they are attractive.  My first try would be $x=(1+x)^(1/3)$  I tried it in Excel and it converged to nine places within about twelve iterations starting from either $1$ or $2$.  Logs are also a good candidate for the right side as they change slowly.

Comment: what is the equality that you mean with log ?

Comment: I didn't see a version with logs here, but was just suggesting that you should look for them in similar problems.  An example would be solving $e^x=100x$.  The function $e^x$ grows rapidly, so (without doing the computation) I would think $x=\frac 1{100}e^x$ was a poor choice.  We could take the logs and get $x=\log(100x)=\log(100)+\log(x)$.  This looks like a much better candidate to me.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the equation $x^3-x-1=0$ is equivalent to
$$x^3 = x+ 1$$
or
$$x = \sqrt[3]{x+1}.$$
Now try Ross' answer.

Comment: yes, i got it. the sequence of approximation to the fixed point is {1.0, 1.25992, 1.31229, 1.32235, 1.32235, 1.32427, 1.32463, 1.322470}

Comment: @J.Klins:   The point is that roots vary slowly while powers vary quickly.  Logs are another good candidate.